# Waiting for a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have the following angularjs code:

```
$scope.clients = commonFactory.getData(clientFactory.getClients());
if ($scope.clients.length > 0) {
    $scope.sampleForm.ClientId = $scope.clients[0].ClientId;
}
```

And the getData function in commonFactory:

```
factory.getData = function (method) {
    method.then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function (error) {
        $rootScope.alerts.push({ type: 'error', msg: error.data.ExceptionMessage });
    });
};
```

The problem is that $scope.clients.length is undefined when it hits that line because of the async call.

Is there a way to not do my length check until I know that $scope.clients has been assigned? I've looked at something like this:

```
$scope.clients = commonFactory.getData(clientFactory.getClients()).then(function () {
    if ($scope.clients.length > 0) {
        $scope.sampleForm.ClientId = $scope.clients[0].ClientId;
    }
});
```

Trying to chain my `then` promises, but no dice... the goal here is to have the getData method to avoid a bunch of boilerplate code for catching errors... maybe I'm going about this wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer with the live demo. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @m59 question down below :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is the most basic situation that promises are for. You simply need to make a promise with `var deferred = $q.defer()` when beginning an async operation, resolve the promise with `deferred.resolve(result)` when the async operation is complete, and return `deferred.promise` in your function. Angular's asynchronous methods do this internally and return promises already, so you can just return those same promises rather than creating new promises with `$q.defer()`. You can attach a `.then` to anything that returns a promise. Further, if you return a value from a `then` function, that value will be wrapped in a promise so that the `then` chain can continue

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('myService', function($q, $timeout, $http) {
  return {
    myMethod: function() {
      // return the same promise that $http.get returns
      return $http.get('some/url');
    }
  };
})

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  myService.myMethod().then(function(resp) {
    $scope.result = resp.data;
  });
})
```

And here is a bit more fun with the chaining:

```
.factory('myService', function($q, $timeout, $http) {
  return {
    myMethod: function() {
      // return the same promise that $http.get returns
      return $http.get('some/url').then(function() {
        return 'abc';
      });
    }
  };
})

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  myService.myMethod().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // 'abc'
    return someOtherAsyncFunc(); // for example, say this returns '123'
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // '123'
  });
})
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks.  One question though- while I notice that in my example, $scope.clients is populated correctly, the call to set ClientId from $scope.clients[0].ClientId doesn't work.  So a bit back to the original problem...?

Comment: @Nicros You're going to keep having issues like this until you have a better understanding of how to approach things with angular. Your code is kind of all over the place. If you make a live demo of your code, I'll be able to help clean it up better. I need to actually those "methods" that mentioned in your code.

Comment: [updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iCaDIVi/6/edit)  Ugh, when I remove the 'length' your code works :) mine still doesn't.  Will work on a better example and update it... cant do it til later though...

Comment: @Nicros yes, you are still missing the point. It's ok, most people do at first (I did). I just answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752659/initialize-controller-by-ajax-request/18753528#18753528 See the first method. Also, repeating the comment I left there, controllers aren't meant to worry about how/when to get data, that's what the services are for. Let a service send the length when the data is ready (promise resolved).

Comment: The only reason to need that length is if you intend to display it, so I'm assuming that is your plan. That being, I see no problem with having a service setup to provide that value to you. That is exactly what I did for the answer I posted in my previous comment. One service method returns all items, while the other will return only the requested item. Also, note the caching so that the ajax call doesn't fire needlessly.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I will test this out ASAP.  Small point- you mention you are creating a service, but you are actually creating a factory, right?  At least that's what I see in the example code above...?

Comment: @Nicros yes, that is a service. The `factory` you see is a place for creating the service. Notice the `return`. What you return from a factory is the service itself. There are many way of creating services as you can read about here: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/understanding-service-types/ I prefer to use the factory. Generally, I wouldn't be instantly returning my service like that. I would instead do `var myPrivateVar = "I'm private!"; myService = { myMethod: function() { //etc } }; return myService;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37215/discussion-between-nicros-and-m59)