# Initialize controller by ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have the AngularJs controller:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
   // as $http.get() is async, success() returns promise but 
   // I need the actual value 'items'
   var promise = $http.get(...)
       .success(function(response) {return response.items;});
   <waitForAjaxCall>
   $scope.items = promise.get?();
   $scope.firstItem = $scope.items[0];

   //do stuff using $scope.firstItem
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', MyController]);
```

How can I ensure that `$scope.items` is initialized by a value returned by the ajax call  before the `$scope.firstItem = ...` assignment? Another approach I see is to wrap `items` in angularjs factory that calls $http, but I still need to wait for the ajax call to complete inside this factory.

Comment: Why not just set the value of $scope.items within the success callback of the promise?

Comment: @Sneaksta adaiu, in this case $scope.firstItem may refer to an uninitialized value

Comment: Ah right. Didn't see the reference to $scope.items on the next line, sorry. Well couldn't you just define $scope.firstItem within the success callback also?

Answer (score 1):

You can't wait synchronously for the Ajax call to complete. You need to initialize the scope within the `success` callback:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    function init(items) {
        $scope.items = items;
        $scope.firstItem = $scope.items[0];

        //do stuff using $scope.firstItem
    }

    $http.get(...)
        .success(function(data) {
            init(data.items);               
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually just do this:

```
<div>{{items[0].name}}</div>
```

Whenever `$scope.items` is set, the first item will be bound there.

Comment: I thought I'd chime in that I chose this approach because it keeps the controller from worrying about how/when it gets data. That is quite the idea of having services, so I say leave it to them and let the controller worry about its concerns (data binding).

Comment: it's very close to what I need, just one more clarification: `$scope.firstItem` is a promise object and in your demo this value is used as {{firstItem}}, so as I understant angular updates a value inside `{{ }}` automagically and uses the value encapsulated by promise instead of a promise itself, right?. Also if it is a promise object, how can I read the firstItem value inside a controller, I can't just do `var myItemName = $scope.firstItem.getItemName()`...

Comment: @Nutel Woaaah that's confusing. Really, all of this is kind of silly. Why not just bind things? `<div>{{items[0].name}}</div>` and ignore the `$scope.firstItem` altogether??

Comment: i was going to use this value inside the controller, foe example `if ($scope.firstItem.name == 'admin') {console.log('admin');}`

Comment: I don't see any need to do so. If I had to guess, you want a conditional binding in your view, in which case, you should bind it conditionally in your view :)

Comment: i use this value for another ajax request

Comment: @Nutel If you're using that value for another ajax request, then it's all the more reason that this should be in services. Also, if the server already has the value, it most likely makes the most sense to get all the information in one call, rather than have such a back and forth between client and server.  I have sufficiently answered your question and much more. Study about services, promises, and best angular design practices.

Comment: Please note that automatic promise unwrapping has been deactivated since angular 1.2.0!

Comment: @Seb that whole part of the answer was useless anyway. I don't know why I kept it there.